# Cassandra, Delete if a set contains value

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh, cql3

I'm a beginner in Cassandra and I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Books(
Title text PRIMARY KEY,
Authors set<text>,
Family set <text>,
Publisher text,
Price decimal
);
```

(the other options are missing because it's only an example)

now I would like to execute this query:

`DELETE Price FROM Books WHERE Authors CONTAINS 'J.K. Rowling' IF EXISTS;`

But it doesn't work. I searched on Google but found nothing.

Hope somebody can help me and sorry if my english is not very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it doesn't work.

That doesn't really give us enough information to help you.  Usually, you'll want to provide an error message.  I built your table locally, inserted data, and tried your approach.  This is the error that I see:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
   message="Some partition key parts are missing: title"
```

`DELETE` requires that the appropriate PRIMARY KEY components be specified in the `WHERE` clause.  In your case, `Authors` is *not* part of the PRIMARY KEY definition.  Given the error message returned (and the table definition) specifying `title` is the only way to delete rows from this table.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> DELETE FROM Books 
    WHERE title = 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets'
    IF EXISTS;

 [applied]
-----------
      True
```

> Can I do a query like this? `UPDATE Books SET Family = Family + {'Fantasy'} WHERE Authors CONTAINS 'J.K. Rowling';`

No.  This fails for the same reason.  Writes in Cassandra (INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs are all writes) require the primary key (specifically, the partition key) in the `WHERE` clause.  Without that, Cassandra can't figure out which node holds the data, and it needs that to perform the write.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another question if it's possible:
can i do a query like this?  UPDATE Books SET Family = Family + {'Fantasy'} WHERE Authors CONTAINS 'J.K. Rowling';

Comment: @Matteo Edit made.